# How to implement an infinite generator?

Tags: python, generator

I am struggling to understand generators. Came across this question and need some step-by-step explanations here.

The problem is asked to create a generator function named `odds`. A generator object created from the generator function should produce the first `count` numbers when used to exhaustion in a `for` loop. For this question, the first odd returned should be 1.

I have trouble understanding this question, what does it mean by "a generator object created from the generator function should produce the first `count` numbers when used to exhaustion in a `for` loop.? I am also wondering why do we need `count -= 1` in this function.

```
def odds(count):
    i = 1 
    while True:
        if i % 2:
            count -= 1
            yield i
            if not count:
                break
        i += 1
```

Comment: When it comes to basics like this, instead of asking (and having to wait) on a Q&A site, I suggest searching Google for one of the many tutorials already out there. What you'll need to grasp is the difference between calling normal functions that use `return` and calling generator functions that use `yield`. 
As for the `count`, it just decreases by 1 every time an odd number is `yield`ed, until it reaches 0 where `if not count:` runs and exits the while loop.

Comment: `count` represents how many odd numbers you want, and is the argument you pass to the function, so the `-=1` is just to count down to 0 and give you however many odd numbers you asked for.

Comment: It helps to use the generator function and observe the results of iterating over it. If you say `x = odds(9)`, then repeated calls to `next(x)` will either give you the value of `i` for each use of `yield i`, or raise `StopIteration` when  the `while` loop finally terminates.

Answer (score 1):

[Generator functions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) are simply functions that `yield` values instead of `return`ing them — and are thus very easy to write. i.e.:

```
def odds(count):
    i = 1
    for _ in range(count):
        yield i
        i += 2

for i in odds(10):
    print(i)
```

There's more to the difference between using the two than that. Here's a more detailed comparison: [Difference between Yield and Return in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-yield-and-return-in-python/).

Stackoverflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, so to gain a deeper understanding of how generators work, I suggest you consult a tutorial on the topic such as: [How to Use Generators and yield in Python](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/).

Comment: That's kind of a circular definition; what does it mean to "yield" a value instead of returning it? (Strictly speaking, the function *does* return something: it returns a value of type `generator`, which would be the starting point for describing what `yield` actually does.)

Comment: @chepner: I simply meant containing a [`yield` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield) instead of a `return` statement — not the dirty details of how it's accomplished internally. Feel free to post your own better answer.